# ¿Como instanciar un objeto public void en JAVA?

Tags: java

Tengo una `public class` donde escribo los métodos y el `main` desde el cual los instancio para resolver los ejercicios/problemas.
Deseo instanciar el siguiente método:

```
public class metodos {
   public void espositivo(int a) {
    if (a>0) {
        System.out.println("El numero es POSITIVO");
    }
    else{
         System.out.println("El numero es NEGATIVO");
    }  
  }
}
```

Este es mi main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class principal {
public static void main (String [] args) {
     metodos op=new metodos();
    Scanner leer= new Scanner(System.in);
    int a=0;

  System.out.println("Ejercicio 2.1");
  System.out.println("");
  System.out.println("Ingrese un numero para saber si es positivo o no");
  a=leer.nextInt();
  //posOneg=op.espositivo(a);
}
}
```

El error aparece en la linea comentada.

Comment: `espositivo` es un método de tipo `void` , **no retorna nada** , por lo tanto no se puede asignar a ninguna variable.   ,  ¿ Qué error muestra?

Comment: @DieDuro que tipo es tu variable posOneg ?

Comment: @Jorgesys esa era justamente mi duda, habia intentado con distintos tipos y siempre me daba error. Por eso al entender que como estaba usando un metodo de tipo `void`no necesitaba crear ninguna variable nueva, la borré usé directamente el metodo.

Comment: @DieDuro si unicamente deseas imprimir el mensaje en consola, tu metodo debe funcionar simplemente llamandolo > op.espositivo(a);

Comment: Es una mala practica de programación en  java crear clases que no empiecen con la primera letra mayúscula, en este caso `metodos` debería ser `Metodos` ya que si no es así aparece un warning indicando este hecho. Lo mismo ocurre con `principal`

Comment: @abrahamhs gracias por el comentario. Voy a empezar a aplicar esta sugerencia. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al ser un metodo **void**, espositivo no devuelve algo. Dentro del mismo imprime algo mediante el **System.out.println()**. Así que solo basta con:

```
op.espositivo(a);
```

Para que así el metodo valide tu **if** y con ello sabrá que imprimir por consola. Espero te haya servido mi explicación, saludos.

Answer (score 3):

El error no lo muestra , pero por su línea comentada el "posible error" es que intenta asignar a una variable el valor que retorna su método `espositivo` , pero dicho método no retorna ningún valor *void*.

Entonces para ejecutar su método bastaría con llamar el método y no asignar a ninguna variable , además añadí un método para validar la entrada *sea entera* en caso no lo sea , vuelva a solicitar la entrada.

```
System.out.println("Ingrese Número");
/* Verificamos si existe un token de tipo int ,
   si no existe volvemos a solicitar la entrada  */
while (!leer.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Vuelva a Ingresar el Número");
    leer.next(); /* Nueva Entrada*/
}
/* Asignamos el valor a la variable a*/
int a = leer.nextInt();
System.out.println(a);
op.espositivo(a);
```

> Recordar que siempre hay que validar entradas si no puede lanzar una
>   exception `NumberFormatException`

Comment: Buen aporte la validación! Entiendo que la validacion son estas lineas:     
    while (!leer.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println("Vuelva a Ingresar el Número");
    leer.next();
    } 
¿Que estoy indicando con ´!leer.hasNextInt()´?

Comment: @DieDuro así es , añadí la validación , recordar que **siempre hay que validar entradas** si no puede lanzar una exception `NumberFormatException` además agregué una edición adicional.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que deseas es únicamente imprimir en consola si el valor de `a` es positivo/negativo, solo llama el método:

```
op.espositivo(a);
```

---

El método `espositivo()` no retorna ningún valor ya que tiene definido un valor de retorno de tipo `void`, si lo que deseas es que retorne un valor booleano simplemente define el tipo de valor de retorno como `boolean` y asegura retornar este tipo de valor dentro del método:

```
public class metodos {
   public boolean espositivo(int a) {
    if (a>0) {
        System.out.println("El numero es POSITIVO");
        return true;
    }
    else{
         System.out.println("El numero es NEGATIVO");
         return false;
    }  
  }
}
```

de esta forma podrás usar el método y te entregaría un valor `true` o `false` dependiendo del valor de `a` :

```
  boolean posOneg = op.espositivo(a);
```